# Is it possible to make alacritty starts with tmux?

Tags: tmux, alacritty

I am using alacritty and tmux together. Is it possible to make tmux run everytime when I launch alacritty?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. In the `shell` option, you can set the program you want to run and even pass in the arguments. For example, in your `alacritty.yml` file, you can set this:

```
shell:
  program: /usr/local/bin/tmux # <- set this to the path of your tmux installation
  args:
    - new-session
    - -A
    - -D
    - -s
    - main
```

Every time you start alacritty, tmux will start a new session and pass the other args.

Answer (score 5):

Or go the easy route and launch your terminal this way:

****alacritty -e tmux****

Comment: Cool idea, but I'm guessing many won't have a terminal open to start another terminal :)

Comment: You don't have to. Not sure what you're talking about. Go to your keybinds and change the launch parameters.

Comment: True, though I don't launch alacritty with a key bind.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using this script:
https://cedaei.com/posts/ideas-from-my-dev-setup-always-tmux/
had it from https://lobste.rs/s/n5blid/ideas_from_my_development_setup_always

and use it in alacritty as:

```yaml
shell:
  program: /home/user/.local/bin/tmux_chooser.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

On the newer versions of Alacritty, which use toml. In the Alacritty config file (usually found in .config/alacritty) you can set this:

```ini
[shell]
program = "tmux"
```

With that set, Alacritty will open with Tmux started by default.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@jogarjia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824037/jogarcia)'s answer i was able to create my solution. If you add these lines to your alacritty config file, Whenever you open a new alacritty window, it will try to connect a tmux session named "general", if it doesn't exist it will create it and attach to it.

```
shell:
  program: /usr/bin/tmux
  args:
    - new-session
    - -A
    - -s
    - general
```

Also please check if the tmux path is correct by:

```
where tmux
```